# Ruby Regular expression: Not able to find word from string

Tags: ruby, regex

I am trying to find word `"the"` that has space before character "t" and after character "e" from string "the the the the" . i am using below regular expression but it is giving me only one word `"the"` instead of two word `'the'`.

```
s="the the the the"
s.scan(/\sthe\s/)
output - [" the "]
```

I was expecting expression to return tow middle word "the". why this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `\s` patterns *consume* the whitespace. The `scan` method only matches *non-overlapping* matches, and your expected matches *are* overlapping.

You need to use [**looakrounds**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to get overlapping matches:

```
/(?<=\s)the(?=\s)/
```

See the [regex demo](http://rubular.com/r/vdebykRXeQ) and a [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/vD3WaC) where `puts s.scan(/(?<=\s)the(?=\s)/)` prints 2 `the` instances.

**Pattern details**:

- `(?<=\s)` - a positive lookbehind that requires a whitespace to be present immediately before the `the`
- `the` - a literal text `the`
- `(?=\s)` -  a positive lookahead that requires a whitespace right after the `the`.

Note that if you use `\bthe\b` (i.e. use word boundaries), you will get all `the` instances from your string as `\b` just asserts the position before or after a word char (letter, digit or underscore).

Comment: "?<=" and "?=" stands for what ??. i cant find its explanation on rubular.com